# stop access to a kafka topic from producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working in a project where the Confluent Kafka operations are provided through IAAS. As part of this, we only allow some pre defined users per application team the ability to read/write from Kafka topics.
The application teams are free to create/delete the user set.

Through our code, we are doing some optimization when there are a number of topics for application teams. For example

1. if an application team has 100 topics and all topics have some common predefined users for read/write, then we apply the permission at application team level (only 1 per user instead of 100)
2. when an application team removes a topic, we remove the specific user permission from the topic level and hard delete the topic 2 weeks later. Removing the permission ensures that the applications will not be able to read/write to the deleted topics.

However the optimization done at 1 is creating a scenario whereby keeping the permission at application level will let the application teams to read/write to the topic even after it is deleted.

I am trying to see if there are any Kafka topic attribute(s) that can be set so as to prevent any read/write to it? In case such a property exists then through our code, we will set such property for deleted topics.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any Kafka topic attribute(s) that can be set so as to prevent any read/write to it?

Sure. You use [ACLs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz) or RBAC

> applications will not be able to read/write to the deleted topics

You can't read/write to deleted topics, anyway. There's different permissions needed for (re)creating topics

Comment: thanks for the link, this is useful. I need to use ACL for my need. However I have ACL permission both for read and write on a topic and need to selectively delete one or both (read/write) permission.  Is there a sample java code to refer to for this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `kafka-acls.sh` CLI script is a wrapper around Java code, yes. It has a remove option.. Kafka is open source, so you look at how that script works

Comment: thanks.. I was able to figure out some more details..